# replace special characters xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I receive an XML that I run through an XSLT process each day; however, the occasional special character causes this to break. I am looking for some utility that will clean the XML & replace special characters with correct html numeric encoding. Just need a utility or an idea.

**Update from comments**

> The XML will sometimes include a
>   special character such as ¢ rather
>   than `&#xA2;` so I need a way to change
>   the special character to the tag

Comment: Can you post a sample? If it is valid XML, it shouldn't break your XSLT. Are you positive it is valid?

Comment: The XML will sometimes include a special character such as ¢ rather than &#xA2; so I need a way to change the special character to the tag. So occasionally its not valid. I just need something to iterate through the XML and compare it to a couple of text files or something.

Comment: Then it is _not_ valid XML. You need to get valid XML from your source.

Comment: exactly...it's 3p software generates the xml so that's why I need some type of clean up utility

Comment: solved this problem used a feature in XSLT called character mapping worked better than using a utility or creating extra script

Answer (score 1):

If your XSLT code can't handle this input XML, then either the input isn't actually XML, or you're presenting it incorrectly to the XSLT processor. The most likely explanation is that the encoding of the file is not what the XML declaration at the start of the file says it is; or perhaps there isn't an XML declaration, so the processor is assuming UTF-8, but it's actually iso-8859-1. The solution may be as simple as adding an XML declaration to the start of the file to declare the encoding as iso-8859-1.

Comment: I had this exact problem just recently; setting the encoding correctly worked.

Answer (score 0):

"Special" characters(Unicode characters not in ASCII) are valid XML, so you should really fix your parser. If that doesn't work, pipe your code through the following filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

input = sys.stdin.read().decode('UTF-8')
for c in input:
    sys.stdout.write('&#%04d;' % ord(c) if c >= 128 else c)
```

Replace `UTF-8` with the document's encoding. Save the above code to `xmlentities`, and call like

```
python xmlentities <broken.xml >fixed.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

**I can't reproduce this problem**

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<t>¢</t>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<t>¢</t>
```